# POST REST Call from C#

Tags: c#, rest

Trying to do POST rest call to my endpoint, but I want to pass empty body and access token. How can I do that ?

My code is :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var endPoint = new Uri("my EndPoint");
  var emptyBody = {}; // Getting an error here, not sure if it is right
  var newPostJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emptyBody);
  var payload = new StringContent(newPostJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var result = client.PostAsync(endPoint, payload).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Can you tell how Can I pass access token and empty body and do you recommend any other change ? It is my first REST CALL.

Comment: `{ }` is javascript for an empty object, but invalid in C#. Use `null` if you want nothing there. Or just use `"{}"` as newPostJson

Comment: FYI: if you get "an error" then please post the exact text

Comment: @HansKeﬆing If I assign null to `var emptyBody` , then it says "Cannot assign null to an implicitly typed variable"

Comment: Yes, `var` and `null` do not work together. Use an explicit type like `object` (or directly set the known json)

Comment: like `object emptyBody = null` ?

Comment: Yes, or maybe `var emptyBody = new object();`

Comment: And how to pass the access token then ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should only have one instance of `HttpClient` in your application so that HTTP connections are [correctly managed](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). That class is thread-safe.

Typically, access tokens are passed as an authorization header, like this:

```
// Declare HttpClient at the class level
private readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();

// Put this code in your method that needs to make an authenticated request
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, myUrl);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Technically, you'll want to use [the `IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to manage your `HttpClient` instances, since a singleton `HttpClient` instance fails to handle DNS changes correctly.

Comment: Indeed, though I figured that would add too much complexity based on where the OP is coming from. Certainly worth mentioning.

Comment: I tried using your code. So, first thing is what should I use in "Bearer" ?
Second thing is it tells me to us `await this.await HttpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true)`. 
Not sure what configureAwait True/False means. 

And third, the code doesnt reach at the line `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`. It doesnt give error but doesnt reach there too.

Comment: The string "Bearer" should be exactly that. It indicates the type of token you're sending is what's known as a bearer token. The variable `token` needs to be assigned to a valid token to access the API. Each API has its own means to issue you a token. It would look something like `var token = "Dk9d9lASLdktu283284Akl";` where that jumble of letters and numbers is the token you need. For production code, you would want that value to come from at least a config file or perhaps a secrets vault, but you can hard code it to get things working.

Comment: If this is a public API with documentation, feel free to link the docs here and I'll have a look.

Comment: I first tried it on POSTMAN and it gives me a 200 response with my token. So, that is good. Now, with "Bearer", my code doesnt reach this line `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` and doesnt even give an error.

Comment: I am using "HttpMethod.Post" though. In POSTMAN, Post method only works when I give empty body and pass application-json as content type in headers.

Comment: I do had to add "configureAwait(false)" in your code. It was giving me compile time error.

Comment: ConfigureAwait() only indicates whether the task must continue on the same thread or not. If the code might be called e.g. from a Windows UI, you would use .ConfigureAwait(true), but if it's library code, probably .ConfigureAwait(false). What error did you get without adding that?

Answer (score 0):

you pass access token and empty body like this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
  try
  {
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
  request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token); // add access token
  string jsonContent=""; // this is an empty json you send it as a body
  request.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

  var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
  var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  }catch(Exception ex){
  }
}
```

Comment: How to add an empty body ?

Comment: the code doesnt come on the last line for `response.content.readAsStringAsync()`. It just executes. How can I get the response ?

Comment: @user18093810 can you try it with try catch and see what is the exception?